# How do I simulate an ADFS IdP to facilitate the testing of my SP code

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs

I need to provide a SAML2.0  based Single Sign On (SSO) feature for my node.js service. This will consume SAML assertions generated by an Identity Provider (IdP) running Active Directory Federated Services (ADFS)

Ideally I would like to set up a test ADFS IdP that I can use to internally generate the SAML assertions. I could then use this to ensure my service handles these assertions correctly.

Unfortunately my company does not use Active Directory and so we cannot just setup a test ADFS platform. The licenses are expensive and so I cannot create an internal test server from scratch.

Is there a low-cost way I can simulate an ADFS IdP to provide a realistic test-bed for my new SSO service?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Azure Active Directory](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/active-directory/) should be very similar to implementations in ADFS (and the federation part is likely identical) and should be just fine for testing of your implementation. You can setup a [free trial account](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/) for Microsoft Azure which includes the Azure Active Directory.

Information about SAML endpoints and SSO process can be found in the [Azure documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn195583.aspx).

Other option is test against another SAML compatible Identity Provider, have a look at [SSO Circle](http://www.ssocircle.com/en/).

Microsoft also offers a [Microsoft Partner Network Action Pack](https://mspartner.microsoft.com/en/uk/pages/membership/action-pack-subscribe.aspx) which enables companies to access a range of software (including Windows Server with ADFS) with development licenses for a reasonable price (few hundred euros). It might be your other option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with using an arbitrary Test-IdP (and don't require AD FS) you could use [Anders Abel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280222/anders-abel)'s **Sustainsys.Saml2 Stub IdP**:

https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/

The Stub Idp is part of the [Sustainsys.Saml2](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2) open source package for ASP.NET.

You can easily create your own IdP tenant configuration and setup assertions meeting your individual requirements.
I use it regularly and am really happy with it!
Thank you, Anders